# Legitimate emails FilteredAsSpam

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline, spam-marked

Freshdesk is sending emails directly (authenticated via SPF) to Office 365 mailboxes but they are consistently being delivered to the junk folder for all recipients.

The following are the authentication results from the headers of a test / example email:

```
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 3.222.0.27)
 smtp.mailfrom=emailus.freshservice.com; mydomain.co.uk; dkim=pass
 (signature was verified) header.d=freshservice.com;mydomain.co.uk;
 dmarc=fail action=none header.from=mydomain.co.uk;compauth=fail
 reason=601
```

The domain's DMARC policy is currently reporting-only (`p=none`) so the fail shouldn't be relevant.

I had an email sent to https://www.mail-tester.com/ which reported a score of 9.1 out of 10.

I ran a summary message trace but, as of at least 2020/10/29 15:07, Exchange Online's diagnostic / analysis tools aren't working as they're reporting `Unknown` for every stage and `Unfortunately, we aren't able to provide an analysis for this message at this time.` which can be seen below:
[image]

I ran extended summary and detailed message traces but I can't see anything useful in the detail which I've included below:

```
recipient_status
recipient@mydomain.co.uk##Receive, FilteredAsSpam
DefaultFolderType:JunkEmail-Mailbox Rules Agent

message_info
2020-10-28T12:14:54.304Z;SRV=DB5EUR03FT006.eop-EUR03.prod.protection.outlook.com:TOTAL-FE=0.253|SMR-PEN=0.223(RENV=0.135|REOH=0.087|SMRPROXY-PEN=0.000)|SMS=0.031;SRV=DB8PR04CA0010.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com:TOTAL-FE=0.102|SMR-PEN=0.092(RENV=0.089|SMRPROXY-PEN=0.000)|SMS=0.036(SMSC=0.027);SRV=CWXP265MB0501.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM:TOTAL-HUB=0.795|SMRE=0.358(CMSGC=0.323|R-CMSG=0.020)|CAT=0.396(CATOS=0.067(CATSM=0.066(CATSM-DC Pre Content Filter Agent=0.063 ))|CATORES=0.304(CATRS=0.303(CATRS-DC Pre Content Filter Agent=0.029|CATRS-DLP Policy Agent=0.020 |CATRS-DC Content Filter Agent=0.096|CATRS-Spam Filter Agent=0.103)))|D-PEN=0.014 |HSDN=0.023;SRV=LO2P265MB1629.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM:TOTAL-DEL=0.424|SDD=0.411(SDDPM=0.263(SDDPM-Mailbox Delivery Filter Agent=0.033|SDDPM-Conversations Processing Agent=0.172|SDDPM-Mailbox Rules Agent=0.043)|SDDSDMG=0.116(SDDR=0.116)|X-SDDS=0.281)

custom_data
S:IncludeInSla=False;S:SlaExclusionReason=EnvelopePriority;S:MailboxDatabaseGuid=6b6d3790-637d-4c8c-b42a-d5a5d73c382f;S:ActivityId=32a050c2-7924-44b7-8ba2-96a947d9ef34;S:Mailboxes=6bcc7ebc-0102-408b-9264-d10e427dbc6d;S:StoreObjectIds=AAAAALp4pq3pUXtGjo0cYcWw7BQHALzKieOJExNKot6w2wTYMk4AAAAAARwAALzKieOJExNKot6w2wTYMk4AAFsG45gAAA==;S:FromEntity=Internet;S:ToEntity=Hosted;S:P2RecipStat=0.004/1;S:MsgRecipCount=1;S:HttpRequestId=eb07df85-24da-4470-98aa-ac106c705165;S:DeliveredViaHttps=True;S:MapiMessageClass=IPM.Note;S:DeliveryLatency=1.573;S:FolderChangedRootcause=<PII:H101(ObrB0A8ZeFUko+0+aR23ay62idD1PotRmD3HXN6Rvx0=):E102(UKCempSMgnZosaCNeGGmjOG90QT+sqgm3q222qm9LFsqMRFakcMd/w0aAbYaUOafsGgyXRWLi8ZQSX5s1a8Yv90PATvhsAPnPDzj8uNivEPIuGwsFLp6n3ZpRxTnTeU8hq7q+kpZUHOK9NSFNNZbiA==)>;'S:CpuUsage=OnInitializedEvent:0.015625;PromoteCreateSession:0.015625;OnPromotedEvent:0.015625;CreateMessage:0.015625;DeliverMessage:0.046875';'S:StoreOperation=STLVRC.C:3;STDBWT.T:181;STRQD.T:44;STDBR.C:20;MCDBDBR.C:13;STDRWT.T:182;MCDBLB.T:7042;MCDBDRWT.T:3;MCDBPR.C:13;RPCDB.T:39;RPCSVR.T:39;MBLB.T:39865;MBMC.T:2;MAPI.C:351;MAPI.T:296;RPC.C:46;RPC.T:294;ROP.C:1071409217;MSCO.T:6;STQIUC.C:6;STQMT.T:160;EXR.T:293;STPPR.C:4;MB.T:294;ST.T:281;STCPU.T:80;STPR.C:16';'S:AssistantLatency=SubstrateSearchEmailItemsProcessor:0.2;ForwardContentClassificationAssistant_Filter:5.8;BigFunnelItemAssistant:2;WeveMessageProcessorB2_Filter:6.9;TeacherAnalyticsSignals_Filter:0.9;WeveMessageProcessorB2:6.3;WeveSignalV2ProcessorB2_Filter:1.1;';S:AttachCount=0;S:E2ELatency=1.576;S:DeliveryPriority=Low;S:PrioritizationReason=AS-Message-Spam;S:OriginalFromAddress=<PII:H101(soVxfaIrjUxM2Dn2phtmtopSVMAstorQz7ylqqDJz3M=):E102(dOjm4tzUyr6woI4Q5M20mRO95y5gBXPRF5uI0bRZQiufOKAXUsLXI3/IRKzjC1mwHKlb2bIKBTTB+C+7p2nYgJaLb3TKW1pS1a/boeL8P/u1ZiwKXm8fqzBmb2sDBv2+zHuCBq9G/Ckh/56vhxxz9A==)>@emailus.freshservice.com;S:AccountForest=GBRP123A002.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
```

As recommended by online stuff, I have checked:

- The Exchange Online spam filters, transport rules, etc but found nothing relevant.
- My mailbox's inbox rules but found nothing relevant.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Why not create a transport rule for these emails to bypass spam filtering?

Comment: I'll do that as a last resort. I prefer to understand and resolve the root cause, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research, there are many people who have encountered this problem, they have already raised it in [uservoice](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/289138-office-365-security-compliance/suggestions/7881927-use-outlook-junk-mail-actions-to-train-hosted-spam), you could vote for it.

The current solution is to create a rule to bypass spam filtering.